# Name of PHP project to create DB schema based on metadata stored in Json files?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

The main purpose of this project is to transform Json files (which contains DB metadata: entities, relations, constraints, etc) into a DB Schema.

The advantage of storing DB metadata in text files is that they can be easily versioned. Also it's easy for developers modify a json file instead of a DB schema.

I cant remember exactly how Json file was, but it's something like:

```
{
   "db": {
     "name":"my-database"
   },
   "tables":[
      {
         "name":"table1",
         "fields":[
            {
               "name":"id",
               "type":"int",
               "autoincrement":"true"
            },
            {
               "name":"name",
               "type":"string",
               "contraint":{
                  "notnull":"true"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Of course I just made this example, but that's the main idea. Using Json files like these the application is capable to create/update a working DB Schema.

I found this project some weeks ago but I cannot remember the name :( this is driving me crazy. Please help me.

Comment: I FOUND IT: http://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: [LIQUIBASE](http://www.liquibase.org/)

Turns out it wasnt a PHP project, anyway it allows to do versioning on DataBases.

You can found a nice article about Liquibase on SitePoint: http://www.sitepoint.com/versioning-your-database-with-liquibase/